# Change title language PlacePicker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to change the language of the title as highlighted in the image below 
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you have tried something???

Comment: @Boss I just implement PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
and  startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity().getApplicationContext()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
And then, its call defaut activity , i dont know how to change title of this

Comment: I don't think you can do that.. but you can use this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlacePicker

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like many other Google's apps, these strings are automaticaly translated to the user language. I'm currently developing an App with PlacePicker, as you can see on the printscreen below (just took it) it's translated to my language. So i tried to change my phone's language to English and it was translated, which means you don't have to worry about the language.

[image]

Comment: very helpful for me. Thanks a lot @GeorgeR

Comment: If you have bilingual application, you can't change phones language just because of your app. I tried changing Applications language but its not working for place picker, other stuffs are localized but not place picker.