# How to change language of placepicker in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, gmsplacepicker

is there any way to change language of place picker without change phone's language ?

in this link use change phone's language method :
[Change title language PlacePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958683/change-title-language-placepicker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way of changing the language through the Google Place Picker API. What you can do is to force the locale of the app activity since changing the language of the phone does work.

A notable SO post discussing this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android?rq=1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have a working sample for this. My activity shows the custom Locale correctly but the PlacePicker started from it shows English only